# converting error with using Convert.ToDateTime in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Before that, the code was working fine, while the program didn't recognize the date format may be because of different cultureInfo.
I am using the Convert.ToDateTime method to convert the DateTime format.

```
Input.TestDate = Convert.ToDateTime(gvwTest.Rows[i].Cells["TxnDate"].Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

As a result, it converted but with incorrect MM and dd.

From **"1/6/2020"** To **"2020-01-06 00:00:00"**

```
string test1 = gvwTest.Rows[i].Cells["TxnDate"].Value.ToString();
string test2 = gvwTest.Rows[i].Cells["TxnDate"].Value.GetType().ToString();

test1 = "1/6/2020";
test2 = "System.String";
```

Comment: Avoid `Convert.ToDateTime`. Instead you should always prefer `DateTime.ParseExact` and `DateTime.TryParseExact`. Microsoft needs to remove the `Convert` class from .NET entirely, imo.

Comment: @Dai I didn't know that Microsoft will remove the Convert, but thanks your info. The project has cooperated with many parties, so I just want to make it more standardised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact`

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("1/6/2020", "M/d/yyyy", provider);
var dateString = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Outputs - 2020-01-06 00:00:00

In my example I have used as input 1/6/2020.

Comment: I found that `DateTime.TryParseExact` would be more suitable to solve my problem, however, I will accept this answer as it gives me some clues. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

While `DateTime.TryParseExact` is definitely better way to go as others pointed out already, still `Convert.ToDateTime` also provides an overload that can accept culture information, in case you want to give it a shot.

Something like this...

```
Input.TestDate = Convert.ToDateTime(gvwTest.Rows[i].Cells["TxnDate"].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Or...

```
Input.TestDate = Convert.ToDateTime(gvwTest.Rows[i].Cells["TxnDate"].Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```